# ERROR org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL Sequence length too large

Tags: java, corba, huawei-mobile-services

After successfully fetching alarms from Corba U2000 server and now reading the values, I am getting the error below

```
ERROR: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Sequence length too large. Only 12 available and trying to assign 31926513  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Sequence length too large. Only 12 available and trying to assign 31926513  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
at org.omg.CosNotification.EventBatchHelper.read(EventBatchHelper.java:57)
at AlarmIRPConstDefs.AlarmInformationSeqHelper.read(AlarmInformationSeqHelper.java:51)
at AlarmIRPConstDefs.AlarmInformationSeqHelper.extract(AlarmInformationSeqHelper.java:26)
at com.be.u2k.Main.getAlarmsList(Main.java:144)
at com.be.u2k.Main.main(Main.java:109)
```

for method `AlarmInformationSeqHelper.extract`

```
// Get all active alarms list
private static void getAlarmsList(ORB orb, AlarmIRP alarmIRP) {
    try {
        ManagedGenericIRPConstDefs.StringTypeOpt filter = new ManagedGenericIRPConstDefs.StringTypeOpt();
        filter.value("($type_name == 'x1')"); // Query new alarms and acknowledge or unacknowledge alarms
        AlarmIRPConstDefs.DNTypeOpt base_object = new AlarmIRPConstDefs.DNTypeOpt();
        BooleanHolder flag = new BooleanHolder();
        AlarmIRPSystem.AlarmInformationIteratorHolder iter = new AlarmIRPSystem.AlarmInformationIteratorHolder();
        StructuredEvent[] alarmList = alarmIRP.get_alarm_list(filter, base_object, flag, iter);
        System.out.println("AlarmIRP get_alarm_list success, flag: " + flag.value + " fetched total: " + (alarmList == null? -1: alarmList.length));

        for (StructuredEvent alarm: alarmList) {
            if (alarm.header != null) {
                System.out.println("fixed_header.event_type.name: " + alarm.header.fixed_header.event_type.type_name
                        + " fixed_header.event_type.domain_name: " + alarm.header.fixed_header.event_type.domain_name);
                if (alarm.header.variable_header != null) {
                    for (Property variableHeader: alarm.header.variable_header) {
                        System.out.println("variable_header.name: " + variableHeader.name + " alarm.header.variable_header.value: " +  variableHeader.value);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (alarm.filterable_data != null) {
                for (Property filterableData: alarm.filterable_data) {
                    System.out.println("data.name: " + filterableData.name);
                    if (filterableData.value != null && filterableData.value.toString().contains("org.jacorb.orb.CDROutputStream")) {
                        StructuredEvent[] filterableDataValues = AlarmInformationSeqHelper.extract(filterableData.value);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("data.value: " + filterableData.value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (ManagedGenericIRPSystem.InvalidParameter e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR get_alarm_list InvalidParameter (Indicates that the parameter is invalid): " + e) ;   
    } catch (ManagedGenericIRPSystem.ParameterNotSupported e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR get_alarm_list ParameterNotSupported (Indicates that the operation is not supported): " + e) ;    
    } catch (AlarmIRPSystem.GetAlarmList e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR get_alarm_list ParameterNotSupported (Indicates exceptions caused by unknown reasons): " + e) ;   
    }
}
```

Or is my way of reading the alarms list incorrect? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the example method below for getAlarmList

```
//Connect to AlarmIRP
AlarmIRP alarmIRP = AlarmIRPHelper.narrow(orb.string_to_object(alarmIrpIOR.value));
StringTypeOpt alarmFilter = new StringTypeOpt();
alarmFilter.value("");
DNTypeOpt base_object = new DNTypeOpt();
base_object.value("");
BooleanHolder flag = new BooleanHolder(false);  // false for iteration
AlarmInformationIteratorHolder iter = new AlarmInformationIteratorHolder();

List<String> alarmIds = get_alarm_list(alarmIRP, alarmFilter, base_object, flag, iter);

private List<String> get_alarm_list(org._3gppsa5_2.AlarmIRPSystem.AlarmIRP alarmIRP, org._3gppsa5_2.ManagedGenericIRPConstDefs.StringTypeOpt alarmFilter, org._3gppsa5_2.AlarmIRPConstDefs.DNTypeOpt base_object, BooleanHolder flag, org._3gppsa5_2.AlarmIRPSystem.AlarmInformationIteratorHolder iter) throws org._3gppsa5_2.AlarmIRPSystem.GetAlarmList, org._3gppsa5_2.ManagedGenericIRPSystem.ParameterNotSupported, org._3gppsa5_2.AlarmIRPSystem.NextAlarmInformations, org._3gppsa5_2.ManagedGenericIRPSystem.InvalidParameter, BAD_OPERATION {
    logger.info("[get-alarm-list][start]");
    alarmIRP.get_alarm_list(alarmFilter, base_object, flag, iter);

    List<StructuredEvent> alarms = new ArrayList();
    EventBatchHolder alarmInformation = new EventBatchHolder();
    short alarmSize = 100;
    List<String> alarmIds = new ArrayList();
    while (iter.value.next_alarmInformations(alarmSize, alarmInformation)) {
        alarms.addAll(Arrays.asList(alarmInformation.value));
        logger.info("Current alarm size:" + alarms.size());
    }

    for (StructuredEvent event : alarms) {
        try {
        //printAlarm(event);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        List<Property> rem = new ArrayList<Property>();
        rem.addAll(Arrays.asList(PropertySeqHelper.extract(event.remainder_of_body)));
        for (Property property : rem) {
        if (!property.name.equals(org._3gppsa5_2.AlarmIRPNotifications.NotifyNewAlarm.ALARM_ID)) {
            continue;
        }

        alarmIds.add(property.value.extract_string());
        }
    }
    logger.info("[get-alarm-list][completed] size :" + alarms.size());

    return alarmIds;
}
```

Comment: Hi egcodes, the way you iterate through the StructuredEvent is working. And also take note of the iter value. In the IDL file of AlarmIRP method get_alarm_list you will see the description there of `get_alarm_list` method. So I used the StructuredEvent array returned by the `get_alarm_list ` method of AlarmIRP if flag is true and in my case the flag is always true. Thanks for this one.

Comment: It is stated there that "This method returns Alarm Informations. If flag is TRUE, all returned Alarm Informations shall be in AlarmInformationSeq that contains 0 or more Alarm Informations. Output parameter iter shall be useless. If flag is FALSE, no Alarm Informations shall be in AlarmInformationSeq. IRPAgent needs to use iter to retrieve them."

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out what is that `filterableData.value.toString()` value that is "org.jacorb.orb.CDROutputStream". It turns out that the property with name "b" is a `TimeBase:: UtcT` according to the docs.

To convert it to correct value which is a utc timestamp, I changed the condition to

```
if (filterableData.name.equals("b") && filterableData.value != null && filterableData.value.toString().contains("org.jacorb.orb.CDROutputStream")) {
    long occuranceTime = TimeTHelper.read(filterableData.value.create_input_stream());
    System.out.println("data.value: " + occuranceTime);
}
```